# Yii2 translation does not work in config/params

Tags: internationalization, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have the following `config/params.php` in my [yii2-basic-app](/questions/tagged/yii2-basic-app):

```
<?php
$siteName = Yii::t('app','Site Name'); //previously, this value had been placed directly in the array just a try to make it available to the translation
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'siteName' => $siteName,
    'textToPrint' => null,
    'meta-description' => $siteName,
];
```

The message `Site Name` is already has a translation in `@app/messages/ar/app.php` and the translation is working fine on the website.

However, when I try to use meta tag description in the main layout like the following:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?= Yii::$app->params['meta-description'] ?>" />
```

So, in any view, if I have set a value to `Yii::$app->params['meta-description']` it should be printed out in the layout while when there is no any supplied value to it, it should print the initial value defined in `config/params.php`.

The problem is, the initial value is printed without translation. This is issue may be solved by translating the string in the main layout as the following:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?= Yii::t('app',Yii::$app->params['meta-description']) ?>" />
```

Due to the above solution I have two questions:

1. Why the string did not be translated in the `config/params.php`?
2. Does the heavy use of `Yii::t()` with many untranslated strings, (in my case, when I decide to override the value `Yii::$app->params['meta-description']` in a view), has any performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1. Because `config/params.php` file will merge with main config **before** initialization of main application. For translation will used `\yii\i18n\I18N` component.
2. `Yii2::t()` is not heavy method. But if you have any problems with performance, you can override this method and execute `Yii:$app->getI18n()->translate()` only for existing strings, or enable cache this values.

Comment: 1: In other words, `params.php` file will be active earlier than translation functions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
public static function translateParams($param)
{
    if (is_array($param)) {
        array_walk($param, function (&$value) {
            $value = \Yii::t("app", $value);
        });
        return $param;
    } else {
        return \Yii::t("app", $param);
    }
}
```